# Preventing Negative Numbers in TextView

Tags: android

I have a TextView that displays a number (in this case, the number is 10).

Now, i have a button so the user has to press that button 10 times in order for the number to hit 0, resulting in moving on to the next level. However,

I can keep hitting that button and it starts its way back into the negatives (-1, -2, etc.).

I tried to think of how I would prevent this but I'm at loss.. any ideas?

-----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------

Okay, so here is my update (I got it to stop at 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (scr >= 1) {

            scr = scr - 1;
           TextView Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
           Score.setText(String.valueOf(scr));
        }

        if (scr == 10) 
        {
               aCounter.start();
        }

        if (scr == 1) 
        {
            aCounter.cancel();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Tap_Game_Activity.this)
             .setTitle("Congratulations!").setMessage("Go to Level 2?")
             .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface AlertDialog, int PositiveButton) {
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_level02_activity);
              }
               })
             .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface AlertDialog, int NegativeButton) {
                   }
                   }).show();
        }

    }});
}
```

(EDIT!): I fixed the AlertDialog by changing the 2 'Else If' statements to just 'If' statements. However, my timer still doesn't work :(, any help?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the code you use to increment the `TextView`'s contents?

Comment: Can you share your code, which is not working.

Comment: I guess it your logic implementation that is adding negative values to TextView.

Comment: remove the button onlicklistener after it reaches 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose number is the variable you are showing in the TextView, consider following code,

```
int number = 10; 

if ( number > 0 ) 
{
    yourTextView.setText ( String.valueOf ( number ) ); 
}
else
{
    // do not set text
}
```

Comment: ahh okay i see, I'm going to try that out right now, and let you guys know how I do. My only concern would be if I hit the button so fast that it goes into the negatives.... I'll try now and let you know

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=10; 

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    i--;
                    t1.setText(""+i);
                    int s1=(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()));
                    if(s1<=0)
                    {
                        b1.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all about Logic.

You have to check condition `if ( YourCount < 0 )` then you have to disable that button or do not set value in textView as per condition.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Android, but more with Java specifically. You just want to make sure that your code doesn't allow you to get below 0.

Your code probably goes something like this:

if button is hit
then subtract 1 from x and setText to x

You want to just throw in something that also checks if number is greater than zero

Like:

If button is hit && x is greater than 0
then subtract 1 from x and setText to x

If that is the case, then I recommend that you step away from the Android platform, and do some Java tutorials and examples.